# Sorting NSDate then associating it with its original unique ID

Tags: sorting, nsarray, nsdate, uid

I have two arrays, one that is made up of NSDates and one that's made up of ints that I use as a unique identifier.

I sort the NSDate array using `sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)` which sorts them perfectly, the problem is I need to associate those dates back to their original UID (the other NSArray).

Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to do some for/if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you associate the two arrays in one NSDictionary? It would then be ok for you to sort them the way you want.

Comment: Oh, good idea.  I forgot all about NSDictionary!  I'll give it a go.

Comment: You got me in the right direction and within a few minutes I figured everything out.  Thanks a bunch!